# Radio Button group in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, radio-button, state, radio-group

I've made the code as simple as possible so it's not complicated. The following code will work correctly for a single formField (each radio group), but how can I use state correctly when I print multiple radio groups to the screen?

In the example below, 2 radio groups will be printed on the screen and if the selected index changes in one, it will also change in the other.

Basically I have data as below;

```
{
  "formfields": [
    {
      "ItemId": 1314,
      "Details": "Has sufficient clearance been allowed for around the outdoor unit?",
      "FieldType": 4, // radio
      "FieldOrder": 2,
      "ChecklistID": 190,
      "IsRequired": true,
      "InitialValue": ["Yes","No"]
    },
    {  
      "ItemId": 1315,
      "Details": "Is the unit installed on a level and sound base?",
      "FieldType": 4,
      "FieldOrder": 3,
      "ChecklistID": 190,
      "IsRequired": true,
      "InitialValue": ["Yes","No"]
      }
    ]
}
```

//App.js;

```
import Radio from "/components/Radio";

const App = (props, {navigation}) => {
const [selected, setSelected] = useState()

  return(
    <View>
      {FormFields.map(item => {                                    
          if (item.FieldType === 4) {
              return (
                  <Radio 
                      selected={selected}
                      options={item.InitialValue} 
                      horizontal={true} 
                      onChangeSelect={(opt, i)=> {
                          setSelected(i);
                      }}/>
              );
          }
        })
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

// Radio.js

```
const Radio = ({options = [], horizontal=false, onChangeSelect, selected}) => {
    return <View style={[horizontal? style.horizontal : style.vertical, {marginTop:5}]}>
        {
            options.map((opt, index) => (
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => onChangeSelect(opt, index)} 
                    style={[style.optContainer, {marginLeft: horizontal? 10: 0, marginTop: horizontal? 0:10}]}>
                    <View style={style.outlineCircle}>
                        {selected == index && <View style={style.innerCircle}/>}
                    </View>
                    <Text style={[style.txt, {color:selected == index ? '#444' : '#777'}]}>{opt}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ))
        }
    </View>
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change multiple radio button values like this, you have to manage
FormFields array for each radio button. Your working code should be like as below. I've added Selected property in array to manage value.

```
    const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
    {
      ItemId: 1314,
      Details:
        'Has sufficient clearance been allowed for around the outdoor unit?',
      FieldType: 4, // radio
      FieldOrder: 2,
      ChecklistID: 190,
      IsRequired: true,
      InitialValue: ['Yes', 'No'],
      Selected: 2,
    },
    {
      ItemId: 1315,
      Details: 'Is the unit installed on a level and sound base?',
      FieldType: 4,
      FieldOrder: 3,
      ChecklistID: 190,
      IsRequired: true,
      InitialValue: ['Yes', 'No'],
      Selected: 2,
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      {formFields.map((item,itemIndex) => {
        if (item.FieldType === 4) {
          return (
            <Radio
              selected={item.Selected}
              options={item.InitialValue}
              horizontal={true}
              onChangeSelect={(opt, i) => {
                let newArr = [];
                formFields.filter((item, index) => {
                  if (index === itemIndex) {                       
                    newArr.push({ ...item, Selected: i });
                  } else {
                    newArr.push(item);
                  }
                  return newArr;
                });
                setFormFields(newArr);
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      })}
    </View>
  );
```